# error: getSystemServise unresolved reference - kotlin android studio

Tags: android, push-notification, kotlin, android-service

hay im new in kotlin and i try to push notification in my app.
Unfortunately I'm having this error: "getSystemServise unresolved reference"
this is my code:

```
        val intent = Intent()
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.activity,0,intent,0)
        val notification = Notification.Builder(this.activity)
                .setContentTitle("time is:")
                .setContentText("text")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon_background)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        val nm:NotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify(0,notification.build())
```

thanks for helpers

Comment: is this code from activity or ...?

Comment: this is from fragment

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I assume your code is inside a `Fragment` and that's why you reference `this.activity` in it multiple times. As [`getSystemService()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService(java.lang.String)) is a method on the [`Context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) class, you need a `Context` instance to call it on. You can get one by either using [`getContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getContext()) or alternatively, the [`getActivity()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getActivity()) which you've already been using (since an [`Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) is also a `Context`).

With Kotlin's property access syntax, this would look something like:

```
// either of these
this.activity.getSystemService(...)
this.context.getSystemService(...)
```

Or even just:

```
// either of these
activity.getSystemService(...)
context.getSystemService(...)
```

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing the same issue.
I got the partial solution with the previous answers, but there is one more thing that you have to mention, i.e. that the variable is *nullable* or not and put the operators accordingly:

```
val downloadManager = context?.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager?
```